# Curl - Sending request to run a php file

Tags: php, bash, shell, curl, request

I have a `php` file in a server, and i want to send a request to run that file via bash script.

If you open the link `domain.com/example.php` in a browser, the `php` will run. But if you send the request via `curl` (from the client computer), sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't work (After each request which works, it doesn't work for several seconds):

```
curl domain.com/example.php
```

The `php` contains a single command: `shell_exec("mkdir worked")`.
Sometimes the `worked` directory is made, sometimes it's not. Tho if you send the request via a browser, every time the `worked` directory is made.

How to send a request from a client computer via bash to the server, so the server will run the `php` file (which is located in the server)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific about how it isn't working.

Comment: @JonStirling Done. See the edits please.

Comment: What is your quesation? Is it how to invoke the PHP script from a remote command line or how to investigate the apparently intermittent nature of the behaviour?

Comment: @symcbean Only the `php` script.